# Apache sends wrong server principal name to Kerberos

Tags: apache2, ldap, debian, kerberos

I am trying to authenticate my apache against kerberos.
I have two websites running on the same server, and I use VirtualHosts to achieve that and set DNS to have two names for this server to have a separate one for each website.
I added recently a new ldap/Kerberos server and trying to connect one of my websites to it, but I failed to get the correct credentials to get it works.
After adding some debugs, I found that apache looks for HTTP/fist-server-name instead of HTTP/second-server-name and for that reason couldn't find the correct principal in Kerberos database and keytab.
How to force apache to do its check against the second server name to validate the call from my second website? It looks adding ServerName attribute in apache configuration is not enough to do that!
I am able to do that by changing the server name orders in hosts file, but this can't help if I want to authenticate from the both server names!

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming that you're using mod_auth_kerb.  You need to add:

```
KrbServiceName Any
```

to your Apache configuration.  This will tell mod_auth_kerb to accept authentications to any principal for which there is a key stored in the keytab it uses, rather than making assumptions about what principal will be used and only accepting authentications to that principal.

Answer (score 4):

You need to identify which Kerberos SPN you want to use for each website. You can check what SPNs are listed in your keytab by running: `klist -k <Keytab>` -- make sure that you're checking the keytab file that Apache uses.

In the `VirtualHost` declaration you need to change the `KrbServiceName` value to match the one that you identified from the keytab. Restart Apache and it should start using that when communicating with Kerberos.

An example would look something like:

```
 KrbServiceName HTTP/yourservice.domain@REALM.COM
```

Make sure that AD has a service account and SPN that matches and that it can resolve via DNS back to the Apache server.

Answer (score 2):

I found this recently in the MIT Kerberos documentation on [Principal names and DNS](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.13/doc/admin/princ_dns.html):

> Applications can choose to use a default hostname component in their service principal name when accepting authentication, which avoids some sorts of hostname mismatches. Because not all relevant applications do this yet, using the krb5.conf setting:

```
[libdefaults]
    ignore_acceptor_hostname = true
```

> will allow the Kerberos library to override the application’s choice of service principal hostname and will allow a server program to accept incoming authentications using **any key in its keytab** that matches the service name and realm name (if given). **This setting defaults to “false”** and is available in releases krb5-1.10 and later.